# Data mining in python

Tags: python, data-mining

I have recently had to learn about data mining algorithms and clustering, and I need some help with a certain problem.

So let us say that we have some already classified data:

```
        X1         X2            C
1       "name1"    [4, 5, 6]     1
2       "name2"    [7, 8, 9]     2
...
```

Where:

1. The 'X1' column - that is the name - contains one out of 7 possible names.
2. The X2 column  contains a list of numbers. (note that the actual list is way larger and this is a simplified version)
3. The 'C' column represents the class of the object.

Now let us say that we have some new object `O3 = ("name6", [1, 2, 3])` and we want to predict the class of the object based on the previously trained data set and its two attributes.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me if there is a simple (preferably efficient) way of predicting the class of new objects such as these.

Comment: well do you have a pre-trained classifier/model first? if not then you need to train/fit one using a classification algorithm and then just use it to make new predictions

Comment: Have you searched for the problem? What did you get?

Comment: The problem is that most tutorials and guides on clustering work with numbers only.  So I am not sure where to start

Comment: Is there a distance metric between the different lists of numbers?